# Correlated subquery on grouped expression - TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: count(1)#382L

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I am trying to do some statistics over some sample data which consists of pairs (a and b values). Some pairs exist multiple times, others not.

```
spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=5, b=10), Row(a=5, b=10), Row(a=5, b=10),
    Row(a=6, b=10), Row(a=6, b=10), Row(a=6, b=10), Row(a=6, b=10), Row(a=6, b=10), Row(a=6, b=10),
    Row(a=5, b=11), Row(a=5, b=11),
    Row(a=6, b=12), Row(a=6, b=12), Row(a=6, b=12), Row(a=6, b=12),
    Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5), Row(a=5, b=5),
]).registerTempTable('mydata')
```

First, I am simply counting how often each pair exists:

```
spark.sql('''
SELECT a, b,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM mydata AS o
GROUP BY a, b
''').show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  6| 12|    4|
|  5|  5|    7|
|  6| 10|    6|
|  5| 10|    3|
|  5| 11|    2|
+---+---+-----+
```

Now, I want to add an additional column containing the percentage of how often a pair exists compared to the total number of pairs with the same value for a. For this, I have tried adding a correlated subquery computing the total:

```
spark.sql('''
SELECT a, b,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    (COUNT(*) / (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydata AS i WHERE o.a = i.a
    )) as percentage
FROM mydata AS o
GROUP BY a, b
''').show()
```

What I am expecting:

```
+---+---+-----+----------+
|  a|  b|count|percentage|
+---+---+-----+----------+
|  6| 12|    4|       0.4|  --> 10 pairs exist with a=6 --> 4/10 = 0.4
|  5|  5|    7|    0.5833|  --> 12 pairs exist with a=5 --> 7/12  =0.5833
|  6| 10|    6|       0.6|  --> ...
|  5| 10|    3|      0.25|
|  5| 11|    2|    0.1666|
+---+---+-----+----------+
```

What I am getting:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o371.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: count(1)#382L
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:90)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find count(1)#382L in [a#305L,b#306L,count(1)#379L]
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(BoundAttribute.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(BoundAttribute.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 80 more
```

This sounds a bit confusing - somehow pyspark wants to access the count of the inner join?

Is there anything wrong with my subquery syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first table, you can calculate the percentage with a window function; `sum(count) over (partition by a)` will sum the `count` by `a` with length of the result not reduced, which allows you to divide by another column directly:

```py
spark.sql('''
    SELECT a, b,
        COUNT(*) as count
    FROM mydata AS o
    GROUP BY a, b
''').registerTempTable('count')

spark.sql('''
    SELECT *, 
           count / sum(count) over (partition by a) as percentage 
    FROM count
''').show()
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
|  a|  b|count|         percentage|
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
|  6| 12|    4|                0.4|
|  6| 10|    6|                0.6|
|  5|  5|    7| 0.5833333333333334|
|  5| 10|    3|               0.25|
|  5| 11|    2|0.16666666666666666|
+---+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't thought about using a window function for this, although it seems to be the much better option compared to using a subquery!
Any idea about the exception? Is using a subquery like that simply not supported?

Comment: You essentially need a join if going without a window function. Basically yes, I don't think a subquery (a filter within a group by) is a valid sql query.

Comment: Mhh - according to https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2728434780191932/1483312212640900/6987336228780374/latest.html correlated subqueries seem to be support in general. Then it's probably the GROUP BY that's causing the issue.